# Message Memory Full in Samsung Galaxy Young Duos & Screenshot transferring

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

I have a Samsung Galaxy Young Duos. I got it for Christmas in 2012 and recently it has begun to tell me i have insufficient storage etc. Today it told me " Cannot receive message, Device to full..."
It's really annoying, what can I do?
I've been deleting messages but it's not helping D:
Thanks !

Comment: wbogacz just added the 'insufficient-memory' tag to your question. I strongly suggest you take a lokk at [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which gives you not only "first aid" but also links to further information sources. Btw: our tag-wikis often do things like that :)

Comment: @psb please don't use edits to add a comment or answer to a question

Comment: [by psb] *The phone memory can be corrupt or there are errors in the software. So to reset remove the battery and the memory card from the phone. Using your PC , scan the memory card for any corrupt files or media files with virus- it is possible when they are downloaded from unsafe sites. If so remove or format the card. Now replace the card and battery and switch on the phone. If the phone hangs up then it is confirmed that the software is corrupt and will need a reinstallation. Seeking help from the authorized service /support centre is most ideal. Take estimate and decide.* (fixya.com)